# Building many btc adress on your website for users?

Tags: website-integration

Hi I am new in this financial trend. I had some experience with exchange trading and investment for Ico. I have an idea and therefore i need to create a ıco website.How can ı add on my ıco site many btc adresses for user who will get invest on my project.

Answer (score 1):

run a bitcoin client with json-rpc enabled. you can then communicate from you backend with this bitcoin rpc interface. See

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC)

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list